# pyamf exclude property not working on db.ReferenceProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, amf, pyamf

I am using pyamf with google app engine. I am trying to exclude a property from the pyamf encoding. This is the syntax I am using:

```
class Comment(db.Model):
    class __amf__:
        exclude = ('article')
    article = db.ReferenceProperty(Article)
    comment = db.TextProperty()
```

This does not work on the ReferenceProperty but if I try the exclude property with the 'comment' attribute it works. I noticed that the exclude property worked on a ReferenceProperty that did not contain a class with another ReferenceProperty attribute. In this case the Article class holds another ReferenceProperty to a another class. Any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be, at least partly, one of syntax -- you want the following:

```
exclude = ('article',)
```

Single parentheses without commas in them are just parenthesized expressions; they are evaluated earlier but do not mean "this is a tuple literal" -- that requires a colon.

Comment: Thanks, I added the comma. however it does not solve the problem with pyamf.